# Bessel Low Pass Algorithm

Tags: java, c, filtering, bessel-functions

I'm looking for a java or c implementation of a Bessel low pass filter. After much searching I haven't been able to find much. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search for *"bessel low pass filter implementation"* turns up [this link](http://forum.cockos.com/archive/index.php/t-76918.html) at the top of the list. (The same discussion thread is posted in an easier-to-read format at [this link](http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=76918).) It seems to have quite a bit of C code fragments as well as discussion on various implementation issues.

Comment: @preventSmash - I think you'll just have to copy-and-paste from the discussion postings. You might also get in touch with the poster to see if sample code is available.